# Get number of lookups in prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

Can we get lookup count for object3.x?

First - look into owned property - no x

Second  - look into prototype object of object3 ->object2 - no x

Third - look into prototype object of object2 -> object 1 - x defined - yes

```
object1 = {x:1};
object2 = Object.create(object1);
object2.y = 2;
object3 = Object.create(object2);
object3.z = 3;

object1.x; // lookup count = 1
object2.x; // lookup count = 2
object3.x; // lookup count = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function for that purpose...

```
function prop_depth(obj, p) {
    var count = 1;

    while(obj && !obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        count++; 
    }
    return obj ? count : -1;
}

prop_depth(object1,'x'); // lookup count = 1
prop_depth(object2,'x'); // lookup count = 2
prop_depth(object3,'x'); // lookup count = 3
```

Comment: `var count 0;`

    `while(obj && !obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && ++count) obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);`

Comment: @qwertymk: Yes, that looks a little nicer.